# apache maven install

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

i  have a problem with installing apache maven on my computer,
i don't know how to resolve it, could anyone suggest some ways of finding out how to resolve the problem, thanks in advance

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.172s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Sep 19 13:00:13 MSK 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
in this directory (C:\Documents and Settings\Saken). Please verify you invoked
Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProject
Exception
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set `MAVEN_HOME` then `set PATH=%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`
set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`
this is the prerequisite for maven configuration.

I assume you already took care of above.

Then create maven project which must have pom.xml and configure accordingly.
Go to the directory where pom.xml is present and run required configuration

Answer (score 0):

Maven need configuration file `pom.xml` in work directory. Run `cd c:/path/to/your/project/folder` and after run `mvn <needed goals>`